# 2 mysql select query is not working

Tags: mysql

Well, following is a mysql query which get data from **user_property** and **offers** table with specific condition. So in this query I need a **id** of user from **users** table (I can identify user **id** from **users** table who have their company name). that's why i'm using a second **Select** query but I can't get the result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_property upr, offers ofr,
        WHERE ofr.property_id = upr.property_id
        AND ofr.agent_id = (
             SELECT id FROM users
             WHERE company_name !=''
       ) ORDER BY accept_ind asc";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sub query might be returning multiple rows

you need to add `limit` statement in sub query

```
(select id from users where company_name !='' LIMIT 1)
```

or use `in` rather of `=`

```
ofr.agent_id IN (select id from users where company_name !='')
```

Comment: and as Abdul Manaf says your query also have syntax error remove `,` from `offers ofr,`

Comment: My Query : `$sql = "select * from user_property upr,  offers ofr where ofr.property_id = upr.property_id  and ofr.agent_id IN (select id from users where company_name !='') order by accept_ind asc";`

Comment: what is the result of this query ? `select id from users where company_name !=''` try it in you database directly

Comment: Yes its successfully showing the id. I check it with while statement and it's showing me.

Comment: try the complete query too in the database

Comment: nop unless you run it and check and paste the error here if there is any error,

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `,` after `offers ofr` and use `IN` Clause

```
select 
    *
from
    user_property upr,
    offers ofr
where
    ofr.property_id = upr.property_id
        and ofr.agent_id IN (select 
            id
        from
            users
        where
            company_name != '')
order by accept_ind asc
```